# Meteor.js / MongoDB : finding a document's place in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**Solved thanks to Hubert OG!**

I have a collection with a popularity property and i do a:

```
var x = collection.find({},{sort: {popularity: 1}})
```

and then i want to find the position (index) of a document (using it's id) by this particular sorting.

How can i do that? Do i have to convert the cursor to an array and loop through it or is there anything built into meteor that can give me an index?

Thank you so much in advance, Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out how many documents have larger popularity:

```
var popularity = Documents.findOne(documentId).popularity;

var morePopular = Documents.find({popularity: {$gt: popularity}}).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly :)

```
var first = collection.find({}).fetch();

var x = collection.find({},{sort: {popularity: 1}}).fetch();

for(var m=0; m<x.length;m++){
    console.log(first.indexOf(x[m].fieldName))
}
```